# sh shell: Redirect output to both terminal and file inside script

Tags: shell-script, shell, logs, io-redirection

How to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file as well as terminal from inside the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILE="/tmp/abc.log"

exec &> >(tee -a $LOG_FILE)

echo "Start"
echo "Hi" 1>&2 
echo "End"
```

I found above script. But this script works only on bash. With sh shell it gives following error:

```
./abc.sh: 5: Syntax error: redirection unexpected (expecting word)
```

I want a script which works with both sh and bash shells.

Comment: And see [Wooledge Bashisms](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) for more non-portable extensions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, `&>` is a `bash` operator (now also supported by `zsh`, while `zsh` always had `>&` for the same like in `csh`), and `>(...)` a `ksh` operator (now also supported by `zsh` and `bash`), neither are `sh` operator. That unquoted $LOG_FILE where you obviously don't want split+glob here, makes it zsh syntax (the only one of those shells where split+glob is not performed implicitly upon unquoted expansions, though in `zsh`, you'd just do `exec >&1 > $LOG_FILE 2>&1`).

In `sh` syntax, you can do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
LOG_FILE="/tmp/abc.log"

{

  # your script here


} 2>&1 | tee -- "$LOG_FILE"
```

Or put everything in a function:

```
#! /bin/sh -
LOG_FILE="/tmp/abc.log"

main() {

  # your script here


}

main "$@" 2>&1 | tee -- "$LOG_FILE"
```

In any case, both that and your `zsh`-style approach would end up printing  error messages on the same resource as open on stdout. So if someone does `your-script > out 2> err`, `err` will be empty and `out` will contain both the normal output and the errors.

To make sure the original destination of output and error is preserved, you could do instead:

```
{
  {
    main "$@" 3>&- | tee -a -- "$LOG_FILE" >&3 3>&-
  } 2>&1 | tee -a -- "$LOG_FILE" >&2 3>&-
} 3> "$LOG_FILE" 3>&1
```

(untested).

Also note that using a file with a fixed name in a world-writable directory such as `/tmp` is bad practice from a security standpoint, as some other users could place a malicious symlink with the same name that would cause you to overwrite the file it points to.

Comment: Why `3> "$LOG_FILE"` on the last line of the last snippet? Is it needed?

Comment: @fra-san, that's to truncate the file (and abort the command if the file can't be opened). Then both `tee`s open the file again in append mode.

Comment: I generally don't use zsh's multios, but it's really nice for this. To fix the issue on the use of the same resource, one could also do `exec 3> $LOG_FILE >&1 2>&2 >&3 2>&3 3>&-`.

Comment: A very instructive answer, as always.  Thank you!  I am puzzled, however, by the first `>&1` subexpression in the expression `exec >&1 > $LOG_FILE 2>&1`.  I thought that, if one omits the fd before the `>`, it defaults to `1`.  This would mean that `>&1`  is the same as `1>&1`.  Am I reasoning correctly?  If so, what is then the point of `1>&1`?  Doesn't it amount to "duplicating" `1` as `1`?

Comment: @kjo, `1>&1` would normally be a no-op if it weren't for the mult_ios feature of zsh whereby if a fd is redirected several times for output, it's redirected to some internal tee-like process that dispatches it to all targets. `> foo > bar` sends stdout to both foo and bar, `>&1 > foo` sends it to the original stdout and to foo.